# Error using Firebase javascript sdk with Facebook sign-in

Tags: firebase, facebook, firebase-authentication

I'm getting the dialog error when trying to sign-in using Firebase Facebook integration.

[image]

Firebase Facebook integration Console:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { signInWithCredential } from "firebase/auth";
import { FacebookAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";

  firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "11111111111111111Eaxos-1111111Yck0olYoK0",
    authDomain: "myapp-123fb.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "myapp-123fb",
    storageBucket: "myapp-123fb.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "1111111111110",
    appId: "1:11111111111:web:111111111f1e8974289764b"
  };
  /***** appID is the same in Firebase console and Developers Facebook console.  ****/
  /***** projectId and authDomain and storageBucket have the same prefix found in the site url ****/

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const app = initializeApp(this.firebaseConfig);
    this.auth = getAuth(app);
  }

  signinWithFacebook(){
    const provider = new FacebookAuthProvider();
    provider.addScope('user_birthday');
    signInWithPopup(this.auth, provider)
    .then((result) => {
...
   })
    .catch((error) => {
...
```

The calls that Firebase does are:

```
https://myapp-123fb.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler
?apiKey=111111111111111axos-111YoK0111111
&appName=%5BDEFAULT%5D
&authType=signInViaPopup
&redirectUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2F
&v=9.22.0
&eventId=3126001481
&providerId=facebook.com
&scopes=user_birthday

https://www.facebook.com/v8.0/dialog/oauth
?response_type=code%2Cgranted_scopes
&client_id=111111111111111168
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmyapp-123fb.firebaseapp.com%2F__%2Fauth%2Fhandler
&state=AMbdmDm_gxcwlIF91Ss7LDTV05kzzdhAf2KNeU_YQEpH8bmU3wh8CIx7aHjY2G6S6O3-ltY57m08J2ce3D2mcEsLOw6CVcUZP_8kQYaYG4EFkcYyKn6H-88Pg2mh49PUM0K_p4_WM4pdP1DE_HBH1z_w593p_Eb4WHrPDZBY-x7SiMl2nkjM3Fe0Yri3TmRdkqEXrKqOfRJ-z6z4wsRpjWjUr_20qf9ybjgvnJLqy5Sfv_Ze32ajWte3tDOGE_OgJT9ra25OrcOGFP9pI0efORoe0cYfZeP1dbgJHZ_d2bYZUmphcKJkoI2BseVDCIobiV1kYoownh2URp4Zbxg7wQ
&scope=public_profile%2Cemail%2Cuser_birthday
&context_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200
```

The client_id in the second url call, is the same found in App Id

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the configuration was incorrect.

First step was to configure the Privacy Policy URL

[image]

[image]

Second step was to configure Facebook Button setting up in Dashboard
The Firebase URL is here in Valid OAuth Redirect URLs

[image]

[image]

And finally I needed to setup Advanced access to public_profile

[image]

[image]